# Browser issue - textbox width

Tags: css

How do I make the text box width look uniform across all browsers?

Please help me,

Comment: http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean a `<textarea>`?

Then just use css and set the width. e.g.

```
<textarea ..other stuff.. style="width:500px">
```

Answer (score 1):

If it needs to be EXACTLY the same in every browser possible, then you will need to use flash or silverlight, as HTML inputs are supposed to be rendered as the user chooses them to be (according to the OS style).
You could do tricks with style to remove the system border and set them to the width you wich in pixels. For example see here: http://freeyourdesign.com/css/css-custom-search-field-or-textfield/

Answer (score 0):

What about setting the width attribute in style

```
<input type='text' id='txt1' style='width: 100px;' />
```

Better create a class and apply that to the textbox

```
<style>
    .txtBox { width: 100px; }
</style>

<input type='text' id='txt1' class='txtBox' />
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are specifying a size in pixels and it is not working (if not, just set a pixel value using "width" in css)?

```
<input type="text" size="20">
```

This should be the same size across all browsers, but so should a pixel value specified in a CSS document. Can you post some code and the specific issues you are having with each browser?

Comment: `input size` is font-dependent. The CSS version is generally more reliable.